# Freemarker equivalent of typescript optional chaining "?"

Tags: typescript, operators, freemarker

Typescript has a nice operator `?` (called optional chaining) that check empty attributes in chains of dots.

Example

```
x?.y?.w?.z
```

means (more or less)

```
if (x !== undefined && x !== null &&
    x.y !== undefined && x.y !== null &&
    x.y.w !== undefined && x.y.w !== null)
then x.y.w.z
else null
```

Is there something similar in FreeMarker template language?

(please notice that `?` Freemarker operator has a completely different meaning).

I tried in docs https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html but I had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest is combining the binary `!` operator (often used like `maybeMissing!'sine default'`) with `()`, like `(x.y.z)!'some default'`. Also you can omit the default value, like `(x.y.z)!`, if you just want it to be an empty string, `0`, or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar operator:

```
(x.y.w.z)!''
```

this checks that `x`, `x.y`, `x.y.w`, `x.y.w.z` are not null, otherwise return `''`